# Unable to open sd folder

Tags: java, android, storage, external

I would like to list my folders in my external card with a push of a button (currently hard coding location just to get the ball rolling)

```
public void onClickBtn(View v) {
    File f = new File("/storage");
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            Log.i("is directory", "here: " + inFile);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs into my logcat:

```
I/is directory: here: /storage/3164-6330
I/is directory: here: /storage/emulated
I/is directory: here: /storage/Private
I/is directory: here: /storage/enc_emulated
I/is directory: here: /storage/self
```

Now I want to repeat the same process but change my path to "/storage/3164-6330" because I know that's where my sd card stores things

```
public void onClickBtn(View v) {
    File f = new File("/storage/3164-6330");
    File[] files = f.listFiles(); //will cause error here
    for (File inFile : files) {
        if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
            Log.i("is directory", "here: " + inFile);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this in my logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array at com.example.abc.MainActivity.onClickBtn(MainActivity.java:141)
```

which is this line:

```
for (File inFile : files) {
```

Does anyone know why I am generating a null array? I have both files and folders in my /storage/3164-6330 path. Thanks!

Comment: did you insert the following permission into your application's manifest file: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: @user3579978 yea, I did

Answer (score 0):

listFiles()
"The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."
-[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles())

Seems that folder doesn't exist. I think the sdcard location depends on the api you are using. mine is storage/sdcard

You may just want to call: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get sdcard location.

EDIT: I apologize i didn't see that final line about knowing those exist. Try the Environment.get call as i had similar issues and ended up with that in my call

Answer (score 0):

try adding File.separator('/') at the end of the folder's name

```
public void onClickBtn(View v) {
    File f = new File("/storage/3164-6330/");
    if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) { // safety check..
        File[] files = f.listFiles(); 
        for (File inFile : files) {
            if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
                Log.i("is directory", "here: " + inFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```